# How to break an array value into 2 rows using jsrender

Tags: javascript, jsrender

This code is run with [JSRender](https://www.jsviews.com/)

```
   <table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="20%">Name</th>
                        <th width="30%">Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{for People}}
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">{{:Name}}</td>
                        <td width="30%">{{:Address}}</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            {{/for}}
```

Here Name is an array and it contains array values, similarly Address is an array values.

When I'm displaying it on grid those values are displayed like 1,2 but ideally I want the data in 2 separate rows.

Comment: Could you please specify what technology do you use? Because this is not a plain JS right?

Comment: I'm using jsrender

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because your closing `{{/for}}` is way to late and should be:

```
        <table id="" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="20%">Name</th>
                    <th width="30%">Address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{for People}}
                  <tr>
                    <td width="20%">{{:Name}}</td>
                    <td width="30%">{{:Address}}</td>
                  </tr>
                {{/for}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: I will have Id for People as Primary key, so for each id I can add multiple people name and address